# how to declare a long long array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

A simple question:
Can someone help me declare a long long array in Java?
I've tried to cast it, but no luck:

```
(long long)[] sum = new (long long)[10];
```

Also, I searched across the internet and didn't really find anyone who uses long long to define an array
Any help please?

Comment: Don't use images to show code.

Comment: `long long` isn't a type in Java.

Comment: "I know for one variable, we can just declare it to be (long long) var;" are you sure about it? Which part of tutorial/specification makes you think it should be OK to use `long long` in Java?

Comment: Obvious [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to do here?

Comment: http://blog.codility.com/2011/03/solutions-for-task-equi.html @Pshemo

Comment: That page mentions multiple languages - the sample code is *not* Java.

Comment: Interesting. This post contained a spam link when I first viewed it. I flagged it, but it got declined because the link was edited out. You can still see it in the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a type called "long long".

Are you sure the code you read was written in Java? Maybe it was a JNI routine that was called into?

it isn't also listed here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `long long` type in Java.

If you need an arbitrarily-long integer type, you can use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), but this is a reference type, and has no "convenient" operators like `+`.

Answer (score 1):

*long long* is not a valid type in java

using a [big integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) would make more sense in this case...

```
BigInteger[] sum = new BigInteger[10];
```